# How to sort companies' data and loop from different 2 sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I want to make macro in VB in Excel:
I have two sheets:

- Sheet **Overview** has the companies' ids column (not repeated) and the type of certificates they may have in columns.
- Sheet **Certificates** has the companies' ids column (repeated) and the type of certificates they have in columns.

I want to make counters for each one id how many certificates in particular certificate type they have and take that value and printed in Overview sheet in certificate columns initially I did my code like this and couldn't continue, can you tell me how to loop on certain company id and check for certificates name to count?

[image]

[image]

and the output like this:

[image]

here is my code:

```
    Sub Macro7()
'
' Macro7 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, -3).Range("A1:B1954").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("certificates").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("certificates").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        ActiveCell.Range("A1:A1954"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("certificates").Sort
        .SetRange ActiveCell.Range("A1:B1954")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
Sub Test2()

      Dim companyID As String
      Dim companyID2 As String
      
      ' Select cell A2, *first line of data*.
      Range("A2").Select
      ' Set Do loop to stop when two consecutive empty cells are reached.
     Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) And IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))
        ' Insert your code here.
        'Get cell value.
        companyID = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(overview).Range("A3").Value
        companyID2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(certificates).Range("A3").Value
        While companyID = companyID2
        If ActiveCell.Value = companyID Then
        
        
       ' Step down 2 rows from present location.
       ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
     Loop
   End Sub
Sub loopRows()
'
' loopRows Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset(-2, -2).Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you could try this formula first on B2 and drag down formula. =IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B,"business")>0,COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B,"business"),"") Adjust appropriately the sheet name and text on C2, D2 & E2

Comment: More appropriately named sheets: B2: =IF(COUNTIFS(Certificates!A:A,Overview!A2,Certificates!B:B,"business")>0,COUNTIFS(Certificates!A:A,Overview!A2,Certificates!B:B,"business"),"")

Comment: You can easily do this with a Pivot Table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please test on your end. This is the same formula as my comments but automated in VBA. You copy-paste it into your workbook.

```
Sub FillFormula()
Dim shOverview As Worksheet, shCert As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set shOverview = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")
Set shCert = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Certificates")

lastRow = shOverview.Cells(shOverview.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Fill formula from row 2 down to the last row
shOverview.Range("B2:B" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(Certificates!A:A,Overview!A2,Certificates!B:B," & _
        DQWrap("business") & ")>0,COUNTIFS(Certificates!A:A,Overview!A2,Certificates!B:B," & _
        DQWrap("business") & ")," & DQ & ")"

shOverview.Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(Certificates!A:A,Overview!A2,Certificates!B:B," & _
        DQWrap("technology") & ")>0,COUNTIFS(Certificates!A:A,Overview!A2,Certificates!B:B," & _
        DQWrap("technology") & ")," & DQ & ")"

shOverview.Range("D2:D" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(Certificates!A:A,Overview!A2,Certificates!B:B," & _
        DQWrap("PMP") & ")>0,COUNTIFS(Certificates!A:A,Overview!A2,Certificates!B:B," & _
        DQWrap("PMP") & ")," & DQ & ")"

shOverview.Range("E2:E" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(Certificates!A:A,Overview!A2,Certificates!B:B," & _
        DQWrap("Art") & ")>0,COUNTIFS(Certificates!A:A,Overview!A2,Certificates!B:B," & _
        DQWrap("Art") & ")," & DQ & ")"

End Sub

' Utility function for wrapping double quotes
Function DQWrap(txt As String) As String
DQWrap = Chr(34) & txt & Chr(34)
End Function

' Utility function for adding double quotes
Function DQ() As String
DQ = Chr(34) & Chr(34)
```